# What could be the origin of a persisting distorted water NMR signal?

Tags: organic-chemistry, water, analytical-chemistry, nmr-spectroscopy, solvents

I am currently running some solvent suppression experiment on water samples. I first run a one scan 1H experiment to get the ''O1P'' and then implement it in the solvent suppression experiment (''zgpurge'' pulse program). However the water signal appears distorted, it is asymmetrical and most likely unphased (other signals appear completly fine), which results in an inefficient solvent suppression experiment. I tried to overcome the problem by performing a 3D shimming, and adjusting the phasing parameters (Autophase during the lock and calibrated the autophase offset) but the problem persisted.
What could be the origin of the problem ? [image]

Comment: You should repeat the solvent suppression experiment with different values of O1P, generally this needs to be optimised in order to get the best suppression — it's not necessarily just the frequency at the top of the water peak.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, what bothers me the most is the odd shape of the signal. Also, It could be impractical to repeat the experiment because it is time-consuming. Best solution for me is to have a perfect symmetrical signal, then taking the O1P at top of the peak is enough.

Comment: I am not familiar with "zgpurge" specifically (you may want to explain in more detail what kind of suppression it involves).

Comment: In my experience, even if you achieve good suppression, the phase of the water peak can vary by quite a bit. Just google for 'water suppression nmr' and you'll see plenty of examples, [this](https://nmr.chem.columbia.edu/content/water-suppression) was the first one I found. I don't know exactly why this is the case, but radiation damping seems like a reasonable guess. In any case, I think it's quite normal to have an out-of-phase H2O peak, and I don't think that your proposed solution will reliably work.

Comment: (Btw, if you can sit at the spectrometer, it doesn't take very long to manually optimise one parameter (O1P) using the gs command. Optimising multiple parameters is a bit harder—as it turns out, [I have a paper on this exact topic](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.analchem.1c01767), which may or may not be interesting—but it might not be necessary at all depending on your use case and what the pulse sequence does. I agree with @BuckThorn that more details about the sequence would be useful; and I think Buck may know more about it than me anyway. ;))

Comment: I tried to obtain the optimal O1P using gs command (I took the O1P corresponding to the minimal FID). However, the obtained O1P was not as effective as when I directly choose it from the top of the signal (I compared S/N of both spectra). As for the efficiency of the suppression with regard to the signal shape, I noticed that the suppression was more effective when the signal was symmetrical, the latter was completely wiped out. However, when it is distorted, it just seems that a new signal is appearing after the suppression (like the rise of the C13 satellites of an organic solvent).

Comment: How can I send you the pulse program ? so that you can have all the details

Comment: Note this has been asked before [here](https://www.researchgate.net/topic/Bruker). You may edit the original post to include the pulseprogram but it suffices to include a description or [reference](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1090780705001631?via%3Dihub)

Comment: @BuckThorn It was me who asked the question in research gate! As a follow up I would like to know if it is possible to tell me how to check for the gradients (as this was the suggestion). I would like to replicate the experiments that have been done by the installation engineer, those are about, the ''gradient recovery'' and ''the gradient profile''. Is it possible to provide a step-by-step procedure on how to conduct those two experiments? btw, the link you provided is exactly about the pulse program I am using. Thank you in advance.

Comment: These are questions for the facility manager. It is a technical question who's answer involves a step-by-step protocol that should be tailored to your instrumentation.

Comment: You can however try editing your question to include what you wrote in the comments. There are various ways to check the gradient calibration, but this is something someone reasonably familiar with the software and equipment should do. Instructions to obtain a gradient profile and calibration should be included described in the instrument's documentation.

Comment: I have to say that, within the framework of quality control (equipment performance control) I redo most of what has been done by the installation engineer, this allows me to check the ''Health'' of the equipment (P90 pulse calibration, Sensitivity, Line shape,...). However, I have never rechecked the gradients since the equipment installation and I don't know how to perform it. As you suggested I should reach a specialized technician. Thank you very much for your feedback.

Comment: A very simple way to check the gradient strength is to run a diffusion experiment, if you have ever done that.

Comment: I have never done it before, but it shouldn't be too complicated. Thank you once again for your help :)